# How to redirect stdout and stderr in bash script with dialog boxes?

Tags: bash, stdout, dialog, stderr

For a single script redirecting stdout and stderr to a file with this:

```
./myscript.sh 2>&1 | tee -a out_file
```

works fine. When I try to run the same way a script containing multiple dialog boxes created with **dialog** command (and calling other scripts)

```
./main.sh 2>&1 | tee -a out_file
```

the out_file contains unwanted characters due to these boxes. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
# myscript.sh

dialog --title "Title" \
--msgbox "Message Box" \
30 120
date
```

generates with:

```
$ ./myscript.sh 2>&1 | tee -a myscript.out
```

multiple lines similar to this one:

```
[36m[44m  [30m[40m[K[22;38H[39;49m(B[m[2;3H[30m[47mMessage Box[22;38H[39;49m(B[m
```

How can I get stdout and stderr without these characters (for main and all subsequent scripts)? That would be in the example the output of **date**. Nice to have would be what a user has entered in an inputbox.

Comment: you could use tr to get rid of it like `tr -d 'ﮛ'` so maybe like `./main.sh 2>&1 | tr -d 'ﮛ' |  tee -a out_file`

Comment: We need details of the scripts and the unwanted characters. Please expand your question to include them.

Comment: Try using dialog --stdout option, `dialog --stdout ...`

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to log color-coded output into a file. See colors and formatting in bash: https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting

You can not arbitrarily change the stdout in this case. Because if you optimize the stdout for logging, then you also change the output wath the users sees.

But you have some possibilities:

- The easiest way is to add in your myscript.sh the command `echo "Message Box printed" >> myscript.out` to record some actions directly in file.
- You can try `./myscript.sh 2>&1 | sed -e "s/<your regex>//g" | tee -a myscript.out` and replace `<your regex>`. But this change output too. So I think that's not what you're looking for.
- Or you create your own descriptor in myscript.sh with `echo "Exit code: $? Textbox $usertext" 1>&4` and modify the dialog command like this `usertext=$(dialog --title "Title" --inputbox "Enter your text:" 30 120 "My Text" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)` Then you can use `. myscript.sh 4>> myscript.out`